# Transform orientation Issues

Tags: edit-mode, extrude, transform-orientation

I 100% know that someone has probably asked this question but why is my orientations (Global and Local) all funked up. Why are my extrusions going off in different directions? Photo on what I mean below...
[image]

Comment: Are you using the transform gizmo? It's shown in the picture.
If you use E for extrude, and it goes up like that on the Z axis, I can't imagine why without seeing your file.

Answer (score 1):

you use **Global** transformation orientation at the moment. only to do is to shift transformation orientation to **Normal** and the gizmo will re-orientate perpendicular to selected plane.